# SSR doesn't work, how to debug further?

Tags: solid-state-relay

I have an AQV252GA ([datasheet](https://api.pim.na.industrial.panasonic.com/file_stream/main/fileversion/549)) but it doesn't work.

Schematic:
[image]

Wiring should be type "C" (in brackets):
[image]

Electrical characteristics:
[image]

I get no voltage with a DMM between pin 5 and GND-5V (tried with and without a load).

I get 0.95V across pins 1 and 2. That seems a little low (should be 1.14V?). I swapped the resistor for 200ohm and still get 0.95V. That seems a little weird, I'd expect voltage drop to change, but who knows what goes on inside the SSR.

I have 2 of these on my board, and both don't work in the same way.

How can I debug further?

---

EDIT: I see this chart:

[image]

At ~25C the dropout voltage is ~1.15V. I measure a 0.95V drop across pins 1 and 2 -- if that's right maybe it's not enough? But why didn't it change when I tried a 200ohm resistor? I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: When you say the source is 'a little sketchy', you actually mean unreliable. Then your question becomes have 'I bought parts from an unreliable source and they behave in an unreliable way'. Better to buy parts with a known history from a reliable supplier. Incidentally, you know what goes on in the SSR because the datasheet tells you much of it.

Comment: The seller gerardemg looks legit enough, but perhaps they got some bad merchandise unknowingly.

Comment: @TonyM No, the question doesn't become something else. Imagine answering the actual question on SO.

Comment: Do you measure a diode (e.g. use DMM diode test) between pins 4-5-6 (diodes as shown in datasheet)? Do you measure voltage across the LED resistor (the 402 / 200Ω) when on?

Comment: @TimWilliams I measured a diode on 5->4 and 5->6. DMM diode mode on the relay input turned it on! It's great to verify the relay works, thanks! The problem must be on the input side. Voltage across the LED resistor is low, ~29mV. I found jumping 3.3V from the MCU supply to relay pin 1 turned on the relay, so the problem is with the 3.3V from my MCU output pin. It measures 3.3V at the relay when unconnected, but when driving the relay LED it's 0.98V. On further digging I found unrelated code with a list of the wrong pins -- that was setting pullups. Fixing that makes everything work! \o/

Comment: *"Imagine answering the actual question on SO"* It's a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. So the problem was the software, which the question makes absolutely no mention of.

Comment: @TonyM The question was how to debug further. You didn't attempt to answer the question, instead you made up your own question. It's not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated code was setting pullups on BOTH the pins. A previous revision of the PCB shuffled the pins around but the code wasn’t updated.